# Launch webview from listactivity

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to implement OnItemClickListener to launch a webview for my listview. Each feed item has a different url(parsed from json) and I want this url loaded in the webview. Also, I get an error that "TextView cannot be resolved to a type" in MainActivity. Content view for MainActivity is activity_main.xml, while I have TextView in feed.xml. The app dosn't crash, but nothing happens when I touch a feed item. Part of my MainActivity is `

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebActivity.class);

            String url = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl)).getText().toString();
            i.putExtra("url", url);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });
```

.......

```
private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
            item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

            String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj.getString("image");
            item.setImage(image);
            item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));

            String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj.getString("url");
            item.setUrl(feedUrl);

            feedItems.add(item);
        }`
```

My WebActivity class is

```
  public class WebActivity extends Activity {

WebView web;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("url");
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Comment: does it start WebActivity when you click on item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code to get the url of clicked item

```
String url = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getUrl()
```

and

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebActivity.class);
               i.putExtra("url", url);
                startActivity(i);
```

In WebActivity

```
 String url="";

      //In onCreate

        url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
       web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
         web.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the method, initially had trouble with implementing this solution coz I didn't know having a clickable url in the feed was interfering with OnItemClickListener. Also tried to implement textview with findviewbyid but this was sending the wrong intent to webactivity. getItemAtPosition eradicates this problem completely

Answer (score 0):

In `WebActivity` Activity use `getIntent` to get `url` which is passed from previous Activity :

```
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
Intent intent=getIntent();
String url;
if(intent !=null)
url=intent.getStringExtra("url");
web.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Our object here is to open the url in the WebActivity that is associated with your feedItems in MainActivity, We have to pass the data from MainActivity to our WebActivity and you are doing right with it. Passing the data from MainActivity to WebActivity by sending "url" with intent.

```
i.putExtra("url", url);
```

now we have passed the data from MainActivity to WebActivity, we have to deal with the data that we had sent from MainActivity.

we can retrieve using  getData() methods on the Intent object. The Intent object can be retrieved via the getIntent() method, here please do make sure if intent is not null.

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  if (null != intent) {
    String stringURL = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    web.loadUrl(stringURL);
  }
```

update your onCreate like this:

```
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

  Intent intent = getIntent();
  if (null != intent) {
    String stringURL = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    web.loadUrl(stringURL);
  }
```

}

Comment: I've edited MainActivity like so 
`String url = ((FeedItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getUrl();
    i.putExtra("url", url);
    startActivity(i);`
And edited WebActivity onCreate as suggested, but the effect is that only feeds without links launch (a blank) webview, nothing happens when I click on feed items with links.

Comment: make sure you get right values when you click on items and read the values that you get on WebActivity too.

Comment: The problem still persists. I think I need to check if the url is null in MainActivity to determine if webview should be launched. Not sure how to go about this, please help @sadiq

Comment: check the values in the logcat, use sysout or Log to know what values you are getting.

Comment: This is the logcat when feed item with null url is clicked. There is no logcat output when feed item with url is selected
03-03 12:36:52.496: D/ViewRootImpl(3671): pckname = mash.android.povi